# Htaccess Mod-Rewrite to Rewrite File Path

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

**I'd like to rewrite calls from:**

> http:// domain.com/index.php?var1=value&var2=alpha&var3=numeric

**To:**

> http:// domain.com

I've tried each of the following below without success. **Can you suggest a better solution?**

```
//#1
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^index\.php\?var1=value&var2=[^&]*&var3=[^&]*$ http://domain.com [R=301]

//#2
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^index\.php\?var1=value&var2=([A-Za-z-]+)&var3=([0-9-]+)$ http://domain.com [R=301]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not match a query string in a rewriterule.

Better use this:

```
# match 'value' (not sure if this is static, otherwise change it)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}   (^|&)var1=value           [NC]
# match all characters from A to Z (case insensitive), including -
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}   (^|&)var2=([A-Z-]+)       [NC]
# match all numbers, including -
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}   (^|&)var3=([0-9-]+)$      [NC]
# if all RewriteCond's are satisfied, this RewriteRule will be executed
RewriteRule ^index\.php$      http://domain.com         [R=301,L]
```

These RewriteCond's will be AND'ed, I've just split them up so you can see what they are doing, but also to match the query string even if the parameters are given in a different order.

Comment: For some reason your answer yields -> domain.com/?var1=value&var2=alpha&var3=numeric. If you add a question mark to the end of the substitution URL string, it yields domain.com. This is what I want, but I'm not sure if this is the correct way to do it.

Comment: @rrrfusco I've edited my answer. Please try it out. Also I don't understand what you mean with 'if you add a question mark to the end of the substition URL string'.. There should only be one question mark in the URL, everything that comes after it will be interpreted as in the query string

Comment: Re: add question mark,  RewriteRule ^index\.php$ domain.com? [R=301,L] I believe the ungreedy modifier '?' stops the string. See http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=192038 Post#6

Comment: @rrrfusco I don't have an ungreedy modifier in my RewriteConds, so this shouldn't be the problem. Also, since I'm only matching alphanumeric characters, this won't match beyond the variable's value boundaries. Are you copying my exact example into your .htaccess, or are you modifying it?